# Is it possible to use local web.config to enable keep-alive?

Tags: iis, keepalive, web.config

Is there any way to enable keep-alive on IIS 7 in a hosted scenario?

I attempted to use the answer to this SO question [Where (or how) is the keep-alive setting in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154599/where-or-how-is-the-keep-alive-setting-in-web-config).

I added the following after the `</configSections>` closing tag:

```
<system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
        <siteDefaults>
            <limits connectionTimeout="00:00:05" />
        </siteDefaults>
    </sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

This is the error I get:

**Unrecognized configuration section system.applicationHost.**

If I follow this MSDN article: [Walkthrough: Creating a Configuration File for Hosted Web Core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693807(v=vs.90).aspx) and add:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.applicationHost"
    type="System.ApplicationHost.Configuration.SystemApplicationHostSectionGroup">
      <section name="sites"
              type="System.ApplicationHost.Configuration.SitesSection"
              allowDefinition="MachineOnly"
              overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
  </sectionGroup>
```

I get the following error:

**It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineOnly' beyond machine.config.**

Answer (score -1):

I have used this in Web Config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="CommandTimeOut" value="1000" />
      <!-- Number of seconds with no activity before the server times out and closes. 
         Set to -1 to never shut down the server. -->
      <add key="keepalive" value="-1" />
  </appSettings>
```